# Magento 2 ignoring new theme

Tags: magento2

I am attempting to create my first Magento 2 theme.

I have created a new theme here:

```
/app/design/frontend/MyComp/MyTheme/
```

I copied the blank theme from `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/` into `MyTheme` and then I created/edited various files, [as per the instructions here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html).

In the Admin Panel I have gone into Stores > Configuration > Design and Ive set the theme to `MyTheme`.

However the front end it appears that my new theme isnt being used.

When I enable template path hints from the Admin Panel, the frontend shows that all the files are being got from here `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/` instead of `/app/design/frontend/MyComp/MyTheme/`.

Can anyone explain why Magento 2 is ignoring my theme, and how I can fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy all the files and folders from here

```
/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/
```

and create `Magento_theme` folder in

```
/app/design/frontend/MyComp/MyTheme/
```

and paste all the files and folder in  `Magento_theme` folder
now flush the magento cache and refresh your home page now you will got what you want.